# Ruby on Rails Exception usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Upon finding a failed validation, invalid? will return false and exit.
If all validations pass, invalid? will return true and the code will continue.
Does the rescue code only run if all validations pass?
If so, what raised errors will it catch?
Lastly why is there no Begin?

```
    def save
      return false if invalid? # invalid? triggers validations
      true
      rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
      # Handle exception that caused the transaction to fail
      # e.message and e.cause.message can be helpful
      errors.add(:base, e.message)
      false
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the rescue code only run if all validations pass?
>   Blockquote

No, it will run if the call of `invalid?` throws an exception of type `StatementInvalid`

> what raised errors will it catch?
>   Blockquote

the call of `invalid?` here is what raises the error

> why is there no Begin?

in ruby, you can remove begin if you rescue from any exception that is raised from methods body so

```
 def method 
  begin 
   #some code
   rescue
   #handle 
  end 
 end
```

equal to

```
 def method 
   some code
   rescue  
   # handle 
 end
```

but the second syntax shorter and cleaner

*Note: it doesn't same right to me to rescue from  `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid`
inside an override to save*

Comment: can invalid? throw a StatementInvalid exception even if all validations pass?

Comment: it's possible but this may be a`Bug` that's why I said it's not right code. `StatementInvalid` is a database execution error. that's mean wrong database query. why do you need to rescue from such error?

Comment: I found that code in a well written rails tutorial that I can't find at the moment. It's used on models with "include ActiveModel::Model" and don't inherit from ApplicationRecord. It works well in my app. Now I understand it more. Thanks